# prove linear map is not surjective

Tags: linear-algebra

Let M: $C^\infty \rightarrow C^\infty$ be the map M:$f \rightarrow tf$ i.e.multiplication by the function t.Show that M is injective, not surjective.

It's very obvious that this map is injective, but how do we prove it's not surjective? Please help me, thank you in advance

Okay, I think that t needs to be non-zero functions. Thus, the only element in the kernel is 0 therefore M is injective. To prove M is not surjective, we need to consider a constant function, $f(x)=c$, which does not have a preimage because $c\over t$ is not in $C^\infty$.

Thank you guys

Comment: What is a feature of every function in the range of $M$?

Comment: I think it's actually _less_ obvious that the map is injective, because you have to use continuity to show that different functions differ at a point other than zero.

Comment: @TrevorWilson: Right, it is a bit more work.

Comment: What exactly is $t$? *Any* function? A constant function? An injective non-zero everywhere function?

Comment: Ok.. What is the domain of the functions? $\Bbb R$? $\Bbb R^n$? Perhaps complex? Is $t$ the *variable* of the functions?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of function t is, but what kind of t can be to make sense in this case?

Comment: @user63219: You can make $t$ be a lot of things that make sense, the only question is which one of those is the one you actually need. It would seem most people interpreted it to be the identity function; more explicitly, $M(f(t)) = tf(t)$.

Comment: If $t$ is a nowhere $0$ smooth function, then, I guess, $M$ is going to be *surjective*.

Answer (score 2):

While $0$ is in the domain of these functions, the *constant* $1$ function is not going to be present in the range of $M$ (because $1/t$ is not defined in $0$).

Comment: Ah, is $t$ a constant? Oh, sorry, I thought, the variable..

Comment: I also became uncertain:)

Comment: I assume the mapping $M$ is on $C^\infty (\mathbb{R})$ and that function $t$ is the identity function on $\mathbb{R}$.  But the question is certainly open to interpretation.